# Change the items of a radio group based on a selection of a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0

I need to change the items of a radio group based on a drop-down selection in RSForm pro.

Right now I'm using the Conditional Fields feature to show different radio group field and that caused too many confusion and was wondering if i could do that trough JavaScript.

Found the Dynamic Drop-down change here

https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/frequently-asked-questions/dynamic-drop-down-change-form-example-.html

how can I change that to show the items for second drop down in radio group insted.

Drop-down name: appliances

items:
Cooker
Oven
...

Radio group name: type

for cooker the radio group items are: Gas, Electric, Dual Fuel, Range
for oven the radio group items are: Single Ovens, Double Ovens

```
<div class="form-group rsform-block rsform-block-appliance{appliance:errorClass}">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label formControlLabel" data-toggle="tooltip" 
title="" for="appliance">{appliance:caption}
<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
<div class="col-sm-9 formControls">
  {appliance:body}
  <span class="formValidation">{appliance:validation}</span>
  <span class="help-block">{appliance:description}</span> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group rsform-block rsform-block-type{type:errorClass}">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label formControlLabel" 
data-toggle="tooltip" title="" for="type">{type:caption}
<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
<div class="col-sm-9 formControls">
  {type:body}
  <span class="formValidation">{type:validation}</span>
  <span class="help-block">{type:description}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your source code? A horizontal scollbar decreases the readability.

Comment: hi, updated the code. {appliance:body} is the drop down field and {type:body} is the radio group.